# Find distance of location to route in Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I´m developing an iPhone app, and I need some help with this case:

I need to check, if user leave google maps route (GMSPolyline) and if distance from user location to nearest point of route is more than 40 meters -- I need to rebuild route.

I can't find the right algorithm to detect if distance from user to route is more than 40 meters.

I've tried to use this method to find projection of user location (converted to CGPoint by CGPointMake) on route :

```
+ (CGPoint)projectionOfPoint:(CGPoint)origPoint toSegmentP1:(CGPoint)p1 p2:(CGPoint)p2 {
// for case line is parallel to x axis
if (p2.y == p1.y) {
    return CGPointMake(origPoint.x, p1.y);

// for case line is parallel to y axis
} else if (p2.x == p1.x) {
    return CGPointMake(p1.x, origPoint.y);
}

// line from segment
CGFloat kKoefLine1 = (p2.x - p1.x)/(p2.y - p1.y);
CGFloat bKoefLine1 = p1.y - kKoefLine1*p1.x;

// perpendicular line
CGFloat kKoefLine2 = -1/kKoefLine1;
CGFloat bKoefLine2 = origPoint.y - kKoefLine2*origPoint.x;

// cross point
CGFloat krossX     = (bKoefLine2 - bKoefLine1)/(kKoefLine1 - kKoefLine2);
CGFloat krossY     = kKoefLine2*krossX + bKoefLine2;

return CGPointMake(krossX, krossY);}
```

Then I calculate distance from returned projection (converted to CLLocation) and user location, but it doesn't works.

P.S.: I will be thankful if solution would be written on swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [`GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPath`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils.html#gabc5e0113367e12d217afad9170257259) function in the `GMSGeometryUtils` module in the Google Maps SDK.

You should be able to use that to calculate what you need.

Pseudocode (not tested):

```
let currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = ...
let routePath: GMSPath = routePolyline.path
let geodesic = true
let tolerance: CLLocationDistance = 40

let within40Meters = GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPath(currentLocation, routePath, geodesic, tolerance)
```

Comment: god bless you! It works perfect and it is exactly what i need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

for swift 5.0 and based on @Arthur answer I wrote follwoing function

```
func isInRoute(posLL: CLLocationCoordinate2D, path: GMSPath) -> Bool
{

    let geodesic = true
    let tolerance: CLLocationDistance = 40

    let within40Meters = GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance(posLL, path, geodesic, tolerance)
    return within40Meters

}
```

Answer (score -2):

While I don't recall much about the GMS SDK off the top of my head, before I give you an answer, I will say that nobody on here will write your code for you. That's your job and should be done on your time. You haven't given any background as to how far you've gotten in terms of calculating routes, whether or not you've figured out how to calculate distance at all, etc.

With that being said, routes on Google Maps are comprised of "legs", which denote a path to take before a turn is made in efforts to reach the end destination. By querying your "route" dictionary, you can extract an array of dictionaries where each element (which is a dictionary) contains metadata about a "leg". You can then loop through that array, go through each dictionary and extract the "distance" value, and sum them to a single "distance" var.

You can recalculate this as often as needed and use a conditional to check whether or not the leg distance sum is < 40M, else rebuild.

link to an article that should help (I didn't have the time to go through the entire thing for you, so do your due diligence and research) [here](https://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/).

Comment: @МаксимЛанской 1. Have you set breakpoints and actually tried debugging by yourself 2. What is the actual problem that you have, detecting user location or determining distance between user location and route destination and 3. Did you click the article that I linked you to? It likely contains something similar to a solution you can use, but spend the time to do your research. It's your job to figure this out with help, it's not up the stack community to do your work for you.